# How to use Angular 5 like the old school of web?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to develop a web application using Angular. Based on our architecture, I need to include Angular and Material as we do with Bootstrap or jQuery or previous versions of Angular JS.

Yet I can't find a way to use Angular that way. All is **cli** which is not conformant to our platform's requirements and team rules.

Is there a way that I can use Angular and Material like the old days, by referencing them in head section of my HTML file?

Answer (score -1):

No, you can't call Angular like before. You have to install Angular from CLI and then start your project but you can call Materialize in the head. Also, you can install it from npm and import it in .angular.cli.json

Comment: I agree with not being able to call Angular from the `index.html`, however, I don't agree that you **have** to install Angular CLI. Using Webpack or SystemJS is an option if you don't want to use Angular CLI.

Comment: Then how do we use hugely beneficial concepts like CDN? How do we create Accelerated Mobile Pages (AMP pages) using Angular? I mean, losing that ability cripples us as true web developers. We need to have control over protocol, and HTML. Am I wrong?

Comment: @DGarvanski I agree with you, i was focusing on CLI, my bad. 
You have in DGarvanski response about the ways of installing Angular and for CDN you can call any other CDN in your HTML code, it's not a problem.

Comment: Yeah, I know I can call any other CDN. But for Angular itself I also want to call a CDN. After all, angular is just a JavaScript library, and should obey JavaScript rules and how to include a JavaScript file in an HTML file.

Comment: "How do we create Accelerated Mobile Pages (AMP pages) using Angular? " — AMP and Angular are designed for completely different kinds of page, they aren't remotely compatible.